# Proper way to send SSH commands to multiple clients with sudo?

Tags: ssh

I have created a very simple shell script to send SSH commands to multiple hosts. Right now I have copied my ssh id so I don't have to use a password to login to the servers. But if I want to do a `apt-get update` for an example then I have to login as root and I am sure this isn't the preferred way to do this? So the question is what is the best way to send multiple ssh commands to multiple client's with sudo rights?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Hosts
hostarray=(
        "host1"
        "host2"
        "host3"
        )

for i in "${hostarray[@]}"; do
    ssh "$i" "command here"
done
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you can't do `sudo command`? **EDIT**: BTW I recommend you try ansible, it enables ssh forks so you can have 3 hosts running the same command in parallel.
Also it's easier to manage multiple hosts/distros

Comment: I am getting this error in return if I try to run sudo through SSH : sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: Btw. I am allready using puppet and I could go with that, but this is just for learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested above, Ansible can handle this more elegantly with the "--become --become-method=sudo --ask-become-password" options. However, you can, for example, put this in a file called /etc/sudoers.d/puppet (assuming your remote user is called puppet -- the naming is optional but it helps me keep things straight):

```
Defaults:puppet    !requiretty

puppet ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This removes the need to type a password and the need for a tty.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the tty error because sudoers is configured to require TTY.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password

You can try running ssh with the option `-tt` which forces tty allocation.  https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1

```
ssh -tt user@host
```

Comment: Aaah that worked, the only issue is that I am getting prompted for a password, but will it be safe enought to create a ssh-rsa key and the disable password for the user ?

Comment: "Safe" is relative based on your requirements.

Comment: Well there is no SSH acces outside from the subnet and it is only a homelab wtith a outgoing webserver so no SSH access outside the network.

Answer (score 0):

you could also copy your public key to `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys` on each remote host, and then

```
ssh root@"$i" "command"
```

If security is not a concern and it's a closed environment, it may make your life easier. Otherwise, I don't recommend it and would set defaults in sudo to not requiretty or perhaps force tty allocation as mentioned above with

```
ssh -tt "$i" "command"
```